# pod with React app failing with with status CrashLoopBackOff on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am new to kubernetes. I am running my kubernetes cluster inside my Docker Desktop VM. Below are the versions

Docker Desktop Community : 2.3.0.4 (Stable)
Engine: 19.03.12
kubernetes: 1.16.5

i created a simple react app. below is the Docker file.

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine    

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH


COPY package*.json ./    
RUN npm install  

# add app files
COPY . ./     

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I built a docker image and ran it. it works fine. I added the image in the below deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test-react-app
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-react-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-react-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-react
          image: myrepo/test-react:v2
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80


---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
  selector:
    app: test-react-app
```

The pod never starts. Below is the events from describe.

```
Type     Reason     Age                  From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>            default-scheduler        Successfully assigned dev/test-deployment-7766949554-m2fbz to docker-desktop
  Normal   Pulled     8m38s (x5 over 10m)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Container image "myrepo/test-react:v2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    8m38s (x5 over 10m)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container test-react
  Normal   Started    8m38s (x5 over 10m)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Started container test-react
  Warning  BackOff    26s (x44 over 10m)   kubelet, docker-desktop  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Below is the logs from the container. It looks as if the container is running..

```
> react-cart@0.1.0 start /app
> react-scripts start

[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://10.1.0.33/
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

Comment: Can you successfully `docker run` the image outside Kubernetes, or does it also exit immediately there?

Comment: i can run docker run, and it works just fine. the problem is only when i run it in kubernetes

Comment: can you do kubectl get pods, in order to see the status of the pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked!!!

I build the react app into a production app and then copied the docker file. I followed the technique given in this link https://dev.to/rieckpil/deploy-a-react-application-to-kubernetes-in-5-easy-steps-516j.